# Way to save an entity framework query for use later - report creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In our company we create custom reports for clients who use our services. The data we collect is contact data (first name, last name, company, email etc) of attendees at events but there is also dynamic data captured. Each event where we collect their data, there are surveys which are custom to the event and company.

For example, at event 123 there might be a survey with 2 questions. Q1 might be an open question/free text, and Q2 will be multiple choice (select n from a list of options that we define).

To code a report like that, it is currently a manual process as we need to

```
1. Filter on all contact data for this event and the specific client
2. Create a temporary table with standard columns (first name, last name, etc)
3. But also with custom columns for however many survey questions we have (2)
4. Populate the temp table with the data from step 1
5. Use a set based update to get survey responses for each question
6. Format the report into the required format (order of columns)
```

This is currently done in a stored procedure, which is time consuming, error-prone and tedious.

Is there a way to

- Somehow save a EF query (like from events in db.Events join ....) somewhere, and able to retrieve that and execute?
- Similarly to the above, save the order of the output columns and have that reflected when the report is run

Currently we do this in sprocs but ideally we want to do this using EF in a report generation tool.

Edit: Here is a stripped down version of the SQL required for a report.

```
-- Step 1. Filter lead data into temp table. Let's say there are 10 leads, and 8 have survey responses for the 2 questions.
SELECT leadID,FirstName,LastName,eMail
INTO #leads
FROM dbo.leads
WHERE eventid = 123 and companyid = 456

-- Step 2 and 3. Create a temporary table with standard contact fields plus survey questions.
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    LeadId NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(100),
    LastName NVARCHAR(100),
    EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100),
    [Question1] NVARCHAR(1000),
    [Question2] NVARCHAR(1000)
)

-- Step 4. Populate temp table.
INSERT INTO #Data (LeadId,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    EmailAddress) 
SELECT leadid,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Email
FROM #leads L

-- Step 5. Use a set based update to get survey responses for each question. 8 leads in each update statement would be updated as 2 leads did not answer the survey.
UPDATE TTARGET SET
Question1 = OA.Title
FROM #Data TTARGET
JOIN answerset answers on TTARGET.LeadId = answers.leadid
JOIN que.answer A on answers.answersetid = A.answersetid
JOIN que.optionalanswer OA ON A.possibleAnswerId = OA.optionalAnswerId
WHERE A.questionid IN ('3A2FFD77-BF37-4580-938A-FF234395B602') AND A.Active = 1

UPDATE TTARGET SET
Question2 = OA.Title
FROM #Data TTARGET
JOIN answerset answers on TTARGET.LeadId = answers.leadid
JOIN que.answer A on answers.answersetid = A.answersetid
JOIN que.optionalanswer OA ON A.possibleAnswerId = OA.optionalAnswerId
WHERE A.questionid IN ('75C5FA00-439F-4DA9-9662-9C683A0E6719') AND A.Active = 1

-- Step 6. Format the report. 
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName
    EmailAddress,
    LeadId,
    Question1 AS 'the title of the first question',
    Question2 AS 'the title of the second question'
FROM #Data
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with a simple set of sample data (in script form) in your question for multiple clients? I am having a difficult time not seeing this as a need not met with vanilla relational data design and a single query (or queries) that is the same for every client, except for a binding to the client identity.

Comment: Michael I edited the post. These report requests come up a few times a month. The question ids and event/company changes per report

Comment: You could do something like an event store, that way you can subscribe to events.

Comment: @andrewb - I appreciate the edit. I guess I was looking more for the sample data of the underlying tables (dbo.leads, que.answer, que.optionalanswer) - Rather than the "this is what I do" with the data, show more "this is what I have". I think you are ultimately asking to get away from the per-client procedural gymnastics you are alluding to. I'm not sure if you have the data structured correctly or if you do and you just don't know how to get at it without the procedural logic.

Comment: I think Entity Framework is the wrong tool for this job.  It wasn't really designed for this.